# Side effect of fixing stale closure by passing a function to setCount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I have a question about stale closure.

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  if (!flag) {
    console.log("before", count);
    setCount(count => count + 2);
    setCount(count => count + 3);
    setCount(count => count + 1);
    setFlag(true);
    console.log("after", count);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Render: {flag + ""}</p>
      <p>Render: {count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output:

```
Render: true

Render: 6
```

Here I have fixed the stale closure setCount by

```
setCount(count => count + 2);
setCount(count => count + 3);
setCount(count => count + 1);
```

But in the console I get

```
before 0
after 0
```

where I expect to get

```
before 0
after 6
```

Can you explain why in the console log count is still 0?

Live demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-joliot-xnmrp

Thanks!

Comment: It's because `setCount()` is asynchronous, that is why `console.log("after", count)` finishes first before actually adding the count value using `setCount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is a const; it cannot possibly change. The purpose of `setCount` isn't to change the variable from the previous render, but to instruct react to render again. On that next render, a new variable will be created with the new value.

If you would like to see the new value, put your console.log in the body of the component, and you'll see it rerender with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

The count variable is set for each render.
On first render the count is 0 and remains 0 till the function exits.
The setCount call in the first render/function execution sets the count value for the NEXT render/function call and during its execution (second render), the const flag is now false so the new count value console log is never executed.

You can see the effect if you place the console logs outside the !flag block